# Azure mobile apps table storage bad request with queryoptions

Tags: azure-table-storage, azure-mobile-services

I've a mobile apps .net backend with Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Storage and .Swagger configured.

When try GetAll from xamarin.forms client, I receive exception "Bad Request" with {[Message, The query specified in the URI is not valid: 'Query option 'Skip' is not allowed. To allow it, set the 'AllowedQueryOptions' property on EnableQueryAttribute or QueryValidationSettings.'.]}

Even if I set AllowedQueryOptions.Supported, the exception persist.

No problem if try to get all/single entity from swagger ui, on xamarin.forms client fail because I can't sync table with pullasync that use skip.

Any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround this.EntitySyncTable.SupportedOptions = MobileServiceRemoteTableOptions.None;